# finding sup,inf, max,min of $A\cap B$ and $A\cup B$, if they exist and proving that $A\cap B$ is bounded.

Tags: analysis

As the title says i am trying to find and prove inf,sup, min, max if they exist for 
$A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$.
And then prove that $A\cap B$ is bounded. Which will actually be easy, after i find all inf,sup etc.

Now for  sets:

$A=${$x\in\mathbb{R}| |\frac{x}{x+1}|\leq1$}

$B=${$\frac{|x|}{|x|+1}|x\in\mathbb{R}$}

I am having problems with defining elements in both union and intersection.
So i would appreciate help with both finding those supremums and infimums, which will help with the last thing, proving that intersection is bounded.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The intersection should be the common elements, which means to solve $x=\frac{|x|}{|x|+1}$ for real $x$ such that $|\frac{x}{x+1}|\leq 1$.  The set $B$ is bounded, because all elements are positive and less than 1. The set $A$ seems also bounded, so their intersection and union should be also bounded.

Comment: Actually, the set $A$ is unbounded, because for example every positive $x$   is in the set $A$ !

Comment: the set $B$  is the interval $[0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that $B$ is the set $[0,1)$, and it's not hard to show that $B\subset A$. Then:

$\inf(A\cap B)=0=\min(A\cap B)$

$\sup(A\cap B)=1$

$\max(A\cap B)$ does not exist.

$A$ is the set of all the real numbers $x\ge-\frac{1}{2}$. It can be showed by solving the inequality $\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|\le 1$.
Then:

$\inf(A\cup B)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$\min(A\cup B)=-\frac{1}{2}$,

$A\cup B$ is not bounded above,

$\max(A\cup B)$ does not exist.

Comment: the set $A$ also contains all nonnegative reals.

Comment: @Svetoslav: Sorry, I had a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: You should edit the $\inf$ and $\min$ of $A\cup B$ to $-\frac{1}{2}$ and the $\sup (A\cup B)$ to $+\infty$

Comment: About $\sup$, it must be a number because must be a bound of the set, the least upper bound.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But we can make a convention to say that $\sup$ is $+\infty$ in the extended reals.